# How to find the interval of validity for differential equations that are difficult to simplify by hand?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the differential equation :

> $$(y^2-1)y' = t-1$$

and was asked to evaluate whether or not there is a unique solution for all values of $t$. Although I solved it using separation of variables, I cannot figure out how to find an explicit range of values of t where the solution is valid. The question and solution is shown in the image below. Thank you for the help!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn178.png]

Comment: I think it's based on the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) or a variant thereof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Considering$$(y^2-1)y' = t-1$$ start switching variables and consider
$$y^2-1=t'(t-1)$$Now $u=t-1$ gives
$$y^2-1=u u'=\frac 12 (u^2)'\implies u^2+C=\frac 13 y^3-y$$

Answer (score 0):

The ODE for the motion is:
$$(y^2-1)y'=t-1~~~(1)$$
$$\int (y^2-1) dy=\int (t-1) dt \implies y^3/3-y=t^2/2-t+C$$
$y(0)=0$ gives $C=0$. So the solution is
$$y^3/3-y=t^2/2-t ~~~(2)$$ see the plot of the trajectory $(t,y)$ below

[image]
The required trajectory is the  one which shows back bending and satisfies $y(0)=0$. This goes upto the point $(t_0,y_0)$ where the tangent to the trajectory is vertical as per Eq. (1) this happens when $y=-1=y_0$ from (2)
by setting $y=-1$ we get $t_0=1\pm\sqrt{7/3}$ ignoring $-$ sign we get the timelimit of the motion as $t \le 1+\sqrt{7/3}$.

Comment: I understand how to solve for this implicit solution and how to plot the trajectory, but is there any way to analytically solve for the limit of t without plotting? I am trying to do it without a computer/plotting technology.

Comment: @Math Looser  Then the suggestion  in the comment (Piccard-) can help you. By the way, understanding any which way is OK. Also it seems all what I wrote and did in my answer is known to you. But then the question is why did you post it in here in an innocent way. Had  you written it up in the question itself, I would have not wasted my time and efforts. Please be precise and expressive next time. Cheers